# Not using an equals to operator while joining in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm performing a series of operations in my Databricks notebook and need suggestions to optimize the code/process. Here are the steps I follow,

1) I am trying to join two dataframes, one has around 200M records while the other has 60K records. The smaller table has 5 columns which have 5 types of email addresses. I've broken this into 5 different dataframes each one having different email address column to avoid using OR operator in the join conditions. Similarly I've broken the large table to just have a unique ID and url column.

Sample code is as follows, The join condition uses "contains" to check on column values. Something like this,

```
df_zp0 = df_z.join(broadcast(pt_t), df_z.url1.contains(pt_t.toAddress2), how = "inner")
```

2) Once all the different columns are joined and the results are stored in 5 DFs I then union the result and create one DF that stores the output.

3) The output from step #2 is joined to the larger table to get the contextual fields.

The problem is this code runs forever because, my understanding is since the joins doesn't use an equal to condition it performs a Cartesian join and then filters the results.

Comment: Have u tried using just one join instead of 5 joins and multiple unions?if the second DataFrame can be successfully broadcasted (max 8gigs), I think the one join with multiple ‘or’ would be better. The 5 joins are still using the big DataFrame each time so there is too much Data movement that’s why taking forever

Comment: You should see the execution plan by doing .explain() on both queries and try to understand the data movement stages